# What's the infimum and supremum of countably infinite ordinals?

Tags: set-theory

I'd say the infimum is $\omega$ and the supremum is $\omega_1$, but I am not too sure - especially about the supremum.

Comment: If you're talking about the *set of countably infinite ordinals*, ordered according to the usual ordering of ordinals, then: (1) There is a minimum (which is then also the infimum) that equals $\omega.$ (2) 
There is not a maximum, but there is a supremum that equals ${\omega}_{1}.$ However, the supremum is not the limit of a (countable) sequence of countable ordinals --- it takes a transfinite sequence of length ${\omega}_1$ to reach ${\omega}_{1}.$

Comment: Thanks. And how would it be for uncountably infinite ordinals? The infimum is clearly $\omega_1$, but what about the supremum? It seems like there shouldn't be any, since they grow so quickly, but that's hardly a proof.

Comment: There is no supremum for the uncountably infinite ordinals. In fact, there is no (ordinal) upper bound for the uncountably infinite ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave Renfro's comments have fully answered your question. However, I think the following will still be helpful to you  - let me go back to the definition of $\omega_\alpha$ in the first place.

*Actually, there are multiple equivalent definitions; I'm just picking one of them here. In some respects it's not the most efficient one, but I do think it's the most intuitive one, especially for this type of question.*

We're most familiar with the cases when $\alpha$ is $0$ or $1$, but the notation "$\omega_\alpha$" makes sense for any ordinal $\alpha$. The ordinal $\omega_\alpha$ is defined recursively as follows: for $\alpha$ an ordinal, $\omega_\alpha$ is the least infinite ordinal which does not inject into any $\omega_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$. It's a good exercise to show that this is in fact well-defined, that is, that $\omega_\alpha$ exists for each ordinal $\alpha$; the proof is via transfinite induction.

Now we can say:

- $\omega_0$ is the least infinite ordinal which is greater than $\omega_\alpha$ for each $\alpha<0$. Since there **aren't** any $\alpha<0$, this means $\omega_0$ is simply the least infinite ordinal - namely, $\omega_0=\omega$.
- Meanwhile, since the only ordinal $<1$ is $0$, this tells us that $\omega_1$ is the least infinite ordinal which doesn't inject into $\omega_0$ - that is, $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal.

The next key fact connects *minima* at one level with *suprema* at the previous level:

- For all $\alpha$, $\omega_\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. Put another way: if $\mu$ is an infinite ordinal, then there is a bijection between $\mu$ and $\mu+1$ (think about Hilbert's hotel), so $\mu+1$ can never be one of the $\omega_\alpha$s.

So, for example, this tells us that $\omega_1$ is both the *least* uncountable ordinal (that's how it's defined) and the *supremum* of the countable ordinals (everything less than it is a countable ordinal, so the only way it could fail to be their supremum is if it were a successor ordinal). This also tells us the following analogue to your question:

> The least ordinal of cardinality $\aleph_1$ (= in bijection with $\omega_1$) is $\omega_1$, and the supremum of the ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_1$ is $\omega_2$.

Note that in your comment, you asked a different question - not about "cardinality $\aleph_1$," but about "uncountable" ordinals. The problem there is that **the uncountable ordinals don't form a set**. More generally, the class of ordinals of cardinality $>\kappa$ is never a set, for any $\kappa$; a set of ordinals has to be *bounded* in cardinality. The point is that "uncountable" is *not* a "higher-order analogue" of "countable" - the right analogue instead is something like "cardinality $\aleph_{17}$" (or perhaps "cardinality $\le\aleph_{17}$," depending on context).

Comment: "which does not inject into any ωβ for β<ω." Don't you mean "$\omega_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$"?

Comment: "- Meanwhile, since the only ordinal $<1$ is $0$, this tells us that $\omega_1$ is the least infinite ordinal which doesn't inject into $\omega_0$ - that is, $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal."
I thought $\omega_0+1$ is an ordinal that doesn't inject into $\omega_0$ and it is certainly smaller than $\omega_1$.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton $\omega_0+1$ **does** inject into $\omega_0$ - think about Hilbert's hotel. It doesn't inject *in an order-preserving way*, but that's not what I said. (Your first comment though is absolutely right - fixed!) More generally, if $\theta$ is an infinite ordinal, then there is a bijection between $\theta$ and $\theta+1$. *Note that this shows a fundamental difference between ordinal arithmetic and cardinal arithmetic: $\omega_0+1\not=\omega_0$ in the sense of ordinal arithmetic, but $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$ in the sense of cardinal arithmetic.*

Comment: Yes, now I get it. I immediately thought of order-preserving injection. My bad.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton It's an easy confusion to fall into, and it's definitely not helped by the use of the same symbols for cardinal and ordinal arithmetic. This, by the way, is the real reason we need both $\aleph$ and $\omega$ notations in set theory - to provide context clues. "$\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$" and "$\omega_0+1\not=\omega_0$" are both true, even though $\aleph_0=\omega_0$, since the meaning of "$+$" in each case is different! Personally I think this is terrible, and we should (a) get rid of $\aleph$-notation entirely and (b) use different symbols for ordinal vs. cardinal arithmetic, but ....

Comment: people keep not electing me math-pope. (An even worse example: the expression "$2^\omega$" frequently has the sense of **cardinal** arithmetic, even though **ordinal** notation has been used! It's really the worst, and the only way to keep it straight is by keeping careful track of context.)

Comment: How come $\aleph_0 = \omega_0$? This is comparing apples and oranges, right? There is a clear difference between cardinals and ordinals in notation. Not so between ordinals and the set they represent, that's confusing.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton Nope - $\aleph_0$ literally *is* the ordinal $\omega_0$. In general, $\aleph_\alpha$ is "the $\alpha$th **initial ordinal**," where "initial ordinal" means "infinite ordinal not in bijection with any smaller ordinal." This is really unfortunate.

Comment: What's especially obnoxious about this is that texts which don't dive into the formal details too carefully *don't* have them equal! E.g. see [this section of the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Initial_ordinal_of_a_cardinal), which *does* distinguish between $\aleph_\alpha$ and $\omega_\alpha$ (but tellingly doesn't say what sort of thing $\aleph_\alpha$ *is*). And, in fact, it's inconsistent with itself - see [the definition of "cardinal"!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition) It's really just the silliest notational ambiguity ever.

Comment: Now there actually *is*, down the road, a reason to cook up a separate notion of cardinality. Without the axiom of choice, we still want to be able to talk about cardinalities, but not all sets are equinumerous with an ordinal now. Frege's idea ("the set of all things equinumerous with ---") doesn't work, since it yields proper classes. The solution is **Scott's trick**: we use Frege's idea with a "cut off." Specifically, given a set $X$, the "Scott cardinality" of $X$ is the set of all sets equinumerous with $X$ *which have minimal rank in the cumulative hierarchy*. (cont'd)

Comment: At this point it's arguably nice to have "$\aleph_\alpha$" denote the *Scott cardinality of $\omega_\alpha$*, which is quite different from $\omega_\alpha$ itself, just to have some uniformity. However, so far as I know no text actually makes this shift, since - ironically - that would cause confusion with the usual ZFC-definition of $\aleph$-numbers! **It's the absolute worst.**